# Residues at a finite point

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus, complex-integration

What is the residue of cotz at z=nπ ,where n is integer ? I have calculated the residue of cotz at z=0 and it is equal to 1 via expansion of cotz ....but how can I find the residue at nπ with the help of power series expansion of cotz ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $\cot \, z=\sum a_kz^{k}$ near $0$ then $\cot \, z=\sum a_k(z-n\pi)^{k}$ neat $n\pi$. To see this simply replace $z$ by $z-n\pi$ and note that $\cot (z-n\pi)=cot \, z$. Hence the residue at $n\pi$ is same as the residue at $0$.

Comment: Thank-you sir ...so if I take the integral of cotz around some contour C then it will be 2πi ..ryt?

Comment: @Henry It will be $2\pi i n$ where $n$ is the number of points of the type $k\pi$ that lie inside the contour.

Answer (score 0):

Since the residue of $\cot(\pi z)$ at $0$ is $1$ and that function is periodic with periode $1$, its residue at each integer multiple of $\pi$ is also $1$.